# Background URLSession + Combine?

Tags: swift, combine

When attempting to send a background request with `URLSession`'s `dataTaskPublisher` method:

```swift
URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "example")) 
     .dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "https://google.com")!) 
     .map(\.data) 
     .sink(receiveCompletion: { print($0) }) { print($0) }
```

I receive the error

```
Completion handler blocks are not supported in background sessions. Use a delegate instead.
```

This makes sense to me, `sink` is a bunch of completion handlers. So, I tried to build a `Subscriber`:

```swift
class ExampleSubscriber: Subscriber {
    typealias Input = Data

    typealias Failure = URLError

    func receive(subscription: Subscription) {
        subscription.request(.max(1))
    }

    func receive(_ input: Data) -> Subscribers.Demand {
        print(input)

        return Subscribers.Demand.none
    }

    func receive(completion: Subscribers.Completion<URLError>) {}

}
```

and subscribe with the `Subscriber`:

```swift
URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "example"))
    .dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string: "https://google.com")!)
    .map(\.data)
    .subscribe(ExampleSubscriber())
```

and I receive the same error:

```
Completion handler blocks are not supported in background sessions. Use a delegate instead.
```

Is it possible to perform a background request using `dataTaskPublisher` or do I *have* to use a delegate to `URLSession`?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44208460/968155

Comment: @NewDev Yeah, I know when using say `dataTask`, you can't use completion handlers and a background session at the same time. I'm specifically asking if it's possible to use Combine and a background session. Particularly when adding a specific `Subscriber`, it seems analogous to a delegate. But I get that it might just not be possible.

Comment: You can’t use `DataTaskPublisher` with background session, as it uses completion handler behind the scenes. You could, obviously just create your own that uses a delegate implementation, but the whole idea of background session is that these are requests that survive not the suspending of the app, but also the app being jettisoned in the natural course of its lifecycle. So when requests are done, OS fires up your app, and neither completion blocks nor combine publishers created before app was suspended exist any more. So it just doesn’t quite make sense to use Combine with background session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`URLSession.DataTaskPublisher` is built on top of `URLSessionDataTask` and sets a completion handler on the task. So you cannot use `DataTaskPublisher` with a background session.

You can find the source code of `DataTaskPublisher` [in the Swift project repo](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Publishers%2BURLSession.swift). Here are [the relevant lines](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Publishers%2BURLSession.swift#L116):

> ```
> let task = p.session.dataTask(
>     with: p.request,
>     completionHandler: handleResponse(data:response:error:)
> )
> ```