# Can't get WatchKit URLSession background to work

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I have a file for a BackgroundSession class

```
class BackgroundSession: NSObject {
  static let shared = BackgroundSession()

  static let identifier = "com.***.bg"

  private var session: URLSession!

  var savedCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)?

  private override init() {
    super.init()

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: BackgroundSession.identifier)
    session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
  }

  func start(_ request: URLRequest) {
    session.downloadTask(with: request).resume()
  }
}

extension BackgroundSession: URLSessionDelegate {
  func urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession session: URLSession) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.savedCompletionHandler?()
      self.savedCompletionHandler = nil
    }
  }
}

extension BackgroundSession: URLSessionTaskDelegate {
  func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    if let error = error {
      // handle failure here
      print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
}

extension BackgroundSession: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
  func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
    do {
      let data = try Data(contentsOf: location)
      let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)

      print("\(json)")
      // do something with json
    } catch {
      print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
  }
}
```

I am listening for background location updates to come in later on

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    print("didUpdateLocations")
    if locations.first != nil {
      let lastLocation = locations.last
      self.lastLocation = lastLocation
      print("doing background work")
      self.getUserData()
      if PubnubController.pubnubChannel != nil {
        PubnubController.sharedClient.publish(["action": "newCoordinates", "data": ["coordinates": ["latitude": lastLocation?.coordinate.latitude, "longitude": lastLocation?.coordinate.longitude]]], toChannel: PubnubController.pubnubChannel!, compressed: false)
      }
    }
  }
```

`self.getUserData()` looks like this

```
func getUserData() {
    print("getUserData")
    if (self.userId != -1 && self.userAuthToken != nil) {
      let httpUrl: String = "https://api.***.com/dev/users/\(self.userId)"
      guard let url = URL(string: httpUrl) else {
        return
      }
      var request = URLRequest(url: url)
      request.setValue(self.userAuthToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
      let session = BackgroundSession.shared
      session.start(request)
    }
  }
```

In my `ExtensionDelegate.swift` I have the typical `func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>)`

with a `for` loop and `switch` set with a case for `WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask` that looks like this

```
case let urlSessionTask as WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask:
              print("WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask")
                // Be sure to complete the URL session task once you’re done.
                urlSessionTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
```

In my controller, I also have pasted the function the class is supposed to call

```
func application(_ application: WKExtension, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession")
    BackgroundSession.shared.savedCompletionHandler = parseUserData
  }
```

It seems that both the delegate function and this pasted function are not being called with my data. I'm having a really hard time trying to understand this background URLSession flow

Note the `BackgroundSession` class came from this Stackoverflow question

[URLSession.datatask with request block not called in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44128358/urlsession-datatask-with-request-block-not-called-in-background)

Answer (score 0):

This [`handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622941-application) is an iOS pattern. This is a method of the [`UIApplicationDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate) protocol. You can’t just add that to some random controller. It’s only applicable for your iOS app's `UIApplicationDelegate`.

For watchOS, I suspect the idea is the same, except rather than calling the completion handler that iOS provides, supply your own completion handler to the `BackgroundSession` that calls the `setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot` of the `WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask`:

```
func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>) {
    // Sent when the system needs to launch the application in the background to process tasks. Tasks arrive in a set, so loop through and process each one.
    for task in backgroundTasks {
        // Use a switch statement to check the task type
        switch task {
        case let urlSessionTask as WKURLSessionRefreshBackgroundTask:
            // Be sure to complete the URL session task once you’re done.
            BackgroundSession.shared.savedCompletionHandler = {
                urlSessionTask.setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot(false)
            }
        ...
        }
    }
}
```

But, effectively, the idea is the same. We’re deferring the `setTaskCompletedWithSnapshot` until `urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession:)` is called.

---

If you want the `BackgroundSession` to call your controller’s parser, you can specify a protocol for that interface:

```
protocol Parser: class {
    func parse(_ data: Data)
}
```

You can then give your `BackgroundSession` a property to keep track of the parser:

```
weak var parser: Parser?
```

You can have the `didFinishDownloadingTo` call the parser:

```
extension BackgroundSession: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: location)
            parser?.parse(data)
        } catch {
            os_log(.error, log: log, "Error retrieving data for %{public}@: %{public}@", downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString ?? "Unknown request", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

You can then have your controller (or whatever) (a) conform to this protocol; (b) implement the `parse(_:)` method of that protocol; and (c) specify itself as the parser:

```
BackgroundSession.shared.parser = self
```

Comment: I'm going to attempt implementing this but if there is data and other methods that need to be called that are in my controller, what is the best way to work with those if it's always being called outside of the context of the controller?

Comment: so now I'm getting a bunch of `No such file or directory` errors on the `BackgroundSession` class. I am using the second example you showed, I added a `print` right before setting the `savedCompletionHandler` and it's not being printed at all, neither is the print statement in the `didFinishDownloadingTo`. I'm not sure this is working at all :/

Comment: There are a number of ways of doing that, but don’t use the `savedTask` or `savedCompletionHandler` for that. Reserve that for just telling the `WKExtensionDelegate` that you’re done. See expanded answer on how you might let the `BackgroundSession` know who should do the parsing.

Comment: @Jordan - Re “no such file”, are you doing any asynchronous dispatching? When `didFinishDownloadingTo` returns, it deletes the temporary files supplied to the `location` URL. And if you do any asynchronous dispatching, it will immediately return and delete the file, possibly doing so before you go to grab the file yourself asynchronously. Make sure to (a) either immediately convert to `Data` and supply that to the parser, or (b) move the supplied temporary file to some location of your choosing.

Comment: so far I'm not really doing anything with the data I'm just logging in the various parts to see if it's all being called

Comment: I'm also not really familiar with Protocols so I'm a little lost in this area