# Download multiple files with operation queue not stable in background mode

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsoperationqueue

Currently what I want to achieve is download files from an array that download only one file at a time and it still performs download even the app goes to the background state.

I'm using Rob code as stated in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32322851/8072787) but he's using **URLSessionConfiguration.default** which I want to use **URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "uniqueID")** instead.

It did work in the first try but after It goes to background everything became chaos. operation starts to download more than one file at a time and not in order anymore.

Is there any solution to this or what should I use instead to achieve what I want. If in android we have service to handle that easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea of wrapping requests in operation is only applicable if the app is active/running. It’s great for things like constraining the degree of concurrency for foreground requests, managing dependencies, etc.

For background session that continues to proceed after the app has been suspended, though, none of that is relevant. You create your request, hand it to the background session to manage, and monitor the delegate methods called for your background session. No operations needed/desired. Remember, these requests will be handled by the background session daemon even if your app is suspended (or if it terminated in the course of its normal lifecycle, though not if you force quit it). So the whole idea of operations, operation queues, etc., just doesn’t make sense if the background `URLSession` daemon is handling the requests and your app isn’t active.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44140059/1271826 for example of background session.

---

By the way, true background sessions are really useful when download very large resources that might take a very long time. But it introduces all sorts of complexities (e.g., you often want to debug and diagnose when not connected to the Xcode debugger which changes your app lifecycle, so you have to resort to mechanisms like unified messaging; you need to figure out how to restore UI if the app was terminated between the time the requests were initiated and when they finished; etc.).

Because of this complexity, you might want to consider whether this is absolutely needed. Sometimes, if you only need less than 30 seconds to complete some requests, it’s easier to just ask the OS to keep your app running in the background for a little bit after the user leaves the app and just use standard `URLSession`. For more information, see [Extending Your App's Background Execution Time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time). It’s a much easier solution, bypassing many background `URLSession` hassles. But it only works if you only need 30 seconds or less. For larger requests that might exceed this small window, a true background `URLSession` is needed.

---

Below, you asked:

> There are some downside with [downloading multiple files in parallel] as I understanding.

No, it’s always better to allow downloads to progress asynchronously and in parallel. It’s much faster and is more efficient. The only time you want to do requests consecutively, one after another, is where you need the parse the response of one request in order to prepare the next request. But that is not the case here.

The exception here is with the default, foreground `URLSession`. In that case you have to worry about latter requests timing out waiting for earlier requests. In that scenario you might bump up the timeout interval. Or we might wrap our requests in `Operation` subclass, allowing us to constrain not only how many concurrent requests we will allow, but not start subsequent requests until earlier ones finish. But even in that case, we don’t usually do it serially, but rather use a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 4 or something like that.

But for background sessions, requests don’t time out just because the background daemon hasn’t gotten around to them yet. Just add your requests to the background `URLSession` and let the OS handle this for you. You definitely don’t want to download images one at a time, with the background daemon relaunching your app in the background when one download is done so you can initiate the next one. That would be very inefficient (both in terms of the user’s battery as well as speed).

> You need to loop inside an array of files and then add to the session to make it download but It will be download asynchronously so it's hard to keeping track also since the files are a lot.

Sure, you can’t do a naive “add to the end of array” if the requests are running in parallel, because you’re not guaranteed the order that they will complete. But it’s not hard to capture these responses as they come in. Just use a dictionary for example, perhaps keyed by the URL of the original request. Then you can easily look up in that dictionary to find the response associated with a particular request URL.

It’s incredibly simple. And we now can perform requests in parallel, which is much faster and more efficient.

You go on to say:

> [Downloading in parallel] could lead the battery to be high consumption with a lot of requests at the same time. that's why I tried to make it download each file one at a time.

No, you never need to perform downloads one at a time for the sake of power. If anything, downloading one at a time is slower, and will take more power.

---

Unrelated, if you’re downloading 800+ files, you might want to allow the user to not perform these requests when the user is in “low data mode”. In iOS 13, for example, you might set [`allowsExpensiveNetworkAccess`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/3235752-allowsexpensivenetworkaccess) and [`allowsConstrainedNetworkAccess`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/3235751-allowsconstrainednetworkaccess).

Regardless (and especially if you are supporting older iOS versions), you might also want to consider the appropriate settings [`isDiscretionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1411552-isdiscretionary) and [`allowsCellularAccess`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1409406-allowscellularaccess).

Bottom line, you want to make sure that you are respectful of a user’s limited cellular data plan or if they’re on some expensive service (e.g. connecting on an airplane’s expensive data plan or tethered via some local hotspot).

For more information on these considerations, see [WWDC 2019 Advances in Networking, Part 1](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/712/).

Comment: thank you for clear things up. Actually my case is when users want to download all the files up to 800files+. That is why I can't keep them download in the foreground or just extend for some extra time in the background. As I saw your answer in another question, It was so clean to use an operation queue because my current technique is using a recursive function to get things done. I want to know if there is another proper way to handle this

Comment: If your app is not running (which is the case with background `URLSession`), an operation queue makes no sense. If you’re OK with your recursive approach, use that (but make sure you’re saving the state in persistent storage for those rare times where your app might have been terminated). Or just all all the requests up front and let the background `URLSession` daemon handle it for you. But operation queues are out of the question.

Comment: thank you for the advice, Rob. but could you suggest to me what approach should I use with this situation since the last project I use this kind of style but sometimes it came up with an unexpected problem. In IOS development. the hardest part is when I need to work with a background that it's the opposite of android development so much

Comment: Like I said, why not just add all the files to be downloaded to the session at once and then just let it go?

Comment: There are some downside with this as I understanding. you need to loop inside an array of files and then add to the session to make it download but It will be download asynchronously so it's hard to keeping track also since the files are a lot. It could lead the battery to be high consumption with a lot of requests at the same time. that's why I tried to make it download each file one at a time.

Comment: I’ve addressed these considerations in my revised answer, above.

Comment: thank you Rob. It's an eye-opening with your answer