# Execute newtork code with app in background

Tags: ios, swift, background, alamofire, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I have this scenario in my app:

I have to execute 2 block of code repeatedly for N times.

in the first block I have to do a network call with Alamofire (I call a HTTP service).
this call returns data and in this data there is a image path that I have to download on device

in the second block I have to download the image and then save it on device

After this start over again for N times.

My problem is that the user can have app in background and I would to like that this process continues when app is in background too.

For this reason, after the Alamofire call, I insert this code for download image:

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "XXXXXX.XXXX")
let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
let url = URL(string: "testurl")
let task = session.downloadTask(with: url!)
task.resume()


func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {

    //save image on device and I recall Alamofire for the next call
}
```

My problem is this: this process doesent execute when app goes in background.
What I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the below delegate,

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
             handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String,
             completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    // send the completion handler as background completion handler
}
```

Please refer the below answer for more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44140059/1244403

Comment: can you explain it?

Comment: I read the link but I dont undrestand how I use it in my case